# Plotting a heatmap based on a scatterplot in Seaborn

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn, visualization, heatmap

Is there any way that I can plot a heatmap in seaborn based on a scatter plot? For instance, I have the following scatter plot and want to plot the corresponding heatmap in such a way that darker spots in the heatmap shows more crowded areas in the scatter plot.

[image]

Comment: Not sure if there's a built-in function, but have you looked up Kernel Density Estimators?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`sns.histplot(x=x_data, y=y_data)`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.histplot.html) would create a 2d histogram of the given data.  [`sns.kdeplot(x=x_data, y=y_data)`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.kdeplot.html) would average out the values, creating an approximation of a 2D probability density function.

Here is a comparison between the 3 plots, using the iris dataset.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(ncols=3, figsize=(15, 4), sharex=True, sharey=True)

iris = sns.load_dataset('iris')
sns.set_style('darkgrid')
sns.scatterplot(x=iris['sepal_length'], y=iris['sepal_width'], ax=ax1)
sns.histplot(x=iris['sepal_length'], y=iris['sepal_width'], ax=ax2)
sns.kdeplot(x=iris['sepal_length'], y=iris['sepal_width'], fill=True, ax=ax3)

ax1.set_title('scatterplot')
ax2.set_title('histplot')
ax3.set_title('kdeplot')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.scatterplot vs sns.histplot vs sns.kdeplot]

Comment: You might also be interested in [`sns.jointplot()`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.jointplot.html) which adds histograms (or kde plots) in x and y direction.

Answer (score 0):

You can have one more variable which keeps track of number of points in its vicinity. And then use that variable ad colour in scatter plot.

Answer (score 0):

[`matplotlib.pyplot.hist2d`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist2d.html) will accomplish this in "regular" matplotlib. It looks like [`seaborn.histplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.histplot.html) can do this as well (scroll down through the examples, it talks about making bivariate histograms when `x` and `y` arguments are specified)